# Oracle coherence*web - session sharing

Tags: session, weblogic, weblogic12c, oracle-coherence

Is it possible to share session between two web applications deployed on different weblogic domains - with Coherence*Web in place?

Comment: no, it is not possible to share sessions from two applications deployed in different WebLogic domains. Use a Coherence cache instead to share data between these applications.

Comment: "no, it is not possible to share sessions from two applications deployed in different WebLogic domains" - you mean even with coherence*web as session persistence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it's possible to share sessions state between different domains (i.e. each domain having a coherence cluster) with Coherence Federation. If you are using WebLogic, go to `Environment > Coherence Clusters > <Your cluster> > Federation` and add a remote participant. If multiple remote participants are there, you can provide a `tangosol-coherence-override.xml` with an appropriate topology / participants.

Answer (score 0):

Session objects can be shared between different applications as shown below:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22839/net_session.htm#COHCG5121

I agree with the accepted answer - Coherence federation provides the ability to replicate the objects to other cluster. But the cluster names have to be specified in the coherence-override.xml file as active participants.

Comment: Try to quote more from the referenced link kindly!